# R: Adding an empty vector to a list

Tags: r, list

In R, when I add an empty vector to a list, it is not in fact added, like below:

```
a = list()
a[[1]] = c()
print(length(a))
```

`length(a)` will be printed 0 in this case, while if I change the 2nd line to `a[[1]] = c(1)`, then length of the list will be 1, as expected. In my implementation, I need the list length to be changed even if I add an empty vector to the list. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `a[[1]] = vector()` will do it. you may need to specify mode of vector too, depending on use case. `c()` returns `NULL`, which won't work

Comment: It's a better idea to just build a list of the right size from the start, e.g. `a <- list(NULL)` or `a <- vector(1, mode = 'list')`, so as not to end up in [the second circle](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#chapter.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using things like `vector()` (logical) and `character()` assigns a specific class to an element you'd like to remain "empty".  I would use the NULL class.  You can assign a NULL list element by using `[<-` instead of `[[<-`.

```
a <- list()
a[1] <- list(NULL)
a
# [[1]]
# NULL
length(a)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: OP was actually pretty close - `a[1] = list(c())` would work too to give the same result.